# App stuck for a long time while launching, Adding Exception breakpoint image attached is printed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, performance, loading

I am trying to launch my IOS APP which complex storyboard. I am assuming there is few noted reason that this is a tabor application so launching is expensive.

But when i add an exception breakpoint I see the app is throwing an exception which can be continued.

This is one are where I am doubt the app is trying to get stuck for long. Can anyone guide how or what this signifies.

[image: Stack-trace on adding exception breakpoint which can be continued]
[image: Stack-trace followed]

Also if anyone can guide me how they have made the complex storyboard launching app which involves following as launch times delayisues

1. Chat Framework XMPP Starting  - ConnectSetup
2. Webservices to validate app authentication and device check.
3. Storyboard to have 30 screens
4. Tab bar application with 5 tabs each first tab calling
   its service

**I have tried following things to reduce the delay but not much optimisation.**

1. Story board partial split.
2. Tabbar to load some services in delayed way not calling all things in one time.
3. Making sure that not all things called in didfinishlaunchfunctionWithOption have huge process expensive operation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea, if your startup involves anything that is likely to take some time, you should move it onto a background thread.

So I would take a look at the [Concurreny Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) and [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/)

After that, I would suggest using [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i) as a means to let your app know that the background tasks has finished. Until that notification has finished, your app should work in a minimal fashion, allowing the user to do as much as possible without the data from the background task.

Comment: Yes I am using dispatch blocks but not much improvements. Initially I see black screen then I put the launch image which waits for a long time, However please let me know why the stack trace stops app if exception break point added, am i doing something that is blocking app launch.